# Webpack watch is failing me

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

EDIT: It's now resolved. Got in to work this morning and thought "have you tried turning it on and off again?". So I did. Removed node_modules, reinstalled all packages - it worked. FML.

---

I'm upgrading to Webpack 4 and can't seem to get the watch to work. 
When I run the watch script everything runs as expected the first time, but errors out during a file update.

The scripts I try:

```
"dev": "cross-env ENV=dev webpack --config config/bundling/webpack.config.js --mode=development",
"watch": "cross-env WATCH=true yarn run dev --watch"
```

(redundancies in the cross-env variables will be fixed later)

The errors I get are the following:

```
"WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to
'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or
'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior.
Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/"

"ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in [MY PATH HERE]
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src main[1]"
```

It seems like it doesn't read my webpack.config.js or the mode variable the on watch? Also, it succeeds in building the bundle, leading me to thing this might be an issue solely with the built-in webpack-dev-server.

I've tried everything I can think of, changing the scripts, changing the syntax of the mode flag, setting mode in webpack.config.js, tried relative paths, tried absolute paths, tried different versions of webpack and webpack-dev-server, moved my config file to the project root, sacrificed a small CPU to the Gods of code - nothing works.

I've been at this for days without any progress. Any help would be appreciated.

Versions:

```
"webpack": "^4.27.1",
"webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
```

Config:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin')
const FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin')

const moduleRules = require('./module.rules')
const config = require('./editable.config')

module.exports = function() {

    const isDev = !!(process.env.ENV === 'dev')
    const isProd = !!(process.env.ENV === 'prod')
    const doServe = !!(process.env.SERVE === 'true')
    const doWatch = !!(process.env.WATCH === 'true')

    const webpackConfig = {

        // Set mode
        mode: isProd ? 'production' : 'development',

        // Entry points.
        entry: config.entrypoints,

        // JS output name and destination.
        output: {
            path: config.paths.public,
            filename: config.outputs.javascript.filename
        },

        // External dependencies.
        externals: config.externals,

        // Custom resolutions.
        resolve: config.resolve,

        // Rules for handling filetypes.
        module: {
            rules: [
                moduleRules.javascript,
                moduleRules.sass,
                moduleRules.fonts,
                moduleRules.images,
            ]
        },

        // Plugins running in every build.
        plugins: [
            new FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin(),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin(config.outputs.css),
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(config.paths.public, { root: config.paths.root }),
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
                context: config.paths.images,
                from: {
                    glob: `${config.paths.images}/**/*`,
                    flatten: false,
                    dot: false
                },
                to: config.outputs.image.filename,
            }]),
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
                context: config.paths.fonts,
                from: {
                    glob: `${config.paths.fonts}/**/*`,
                    flatten: false,
                    dot: false
                },
                to: config.outputs.font.filename,
            }]),
        ],

        devtool: isDev ? config.settings.sourceMaps : false,

        watch: doWatch
    }

    // Set BrowserSync settings if serving
    if (doServe) {
        // setting our default settings...
        const browserSyncSettings = {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 3000,
            proxy: process.env.HOME,
            files: [
                {
                    match: ['../../**/*.php'],
                    fn: function (event, file) {
                        if (event === 'change') {
                            this.reload()
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }

        // ...and overwriting them with user settings
        Object.assign(browserSyncSettings, config.settings.browserSync)

        webpackConfig.plugins.push(new BrowserSyncPlugin(browserSyncSettings))
    }

    return webpackConfig;
}
```

Config, part 2

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {

    paths: {
        root: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../'),
        public: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../public'),
        src: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../src'),
        javascript: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../src/js'),
        sass: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../src/sass'),
        fonts: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../src/fonts'),
        images: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../src/images'),
        relative: '../../',
        external: /node_modules/
    },


    entrypoints: {
        main: ['./src/js/app.js', './src/sass/style.scss']
    },

    outputs: {
        javascript: { filename: 'js/[name].js' },
        css: { filename: 'css/[name].css' },
        font: { filename: 'fonts/[path][name].[ext]' },
        image: { filename: 'images/[path][name].[ext]' }
    },

    externals: {
    },

    resolve: {
    },


    settings: {
        sourceMaps: 'cheap-module-source-map',
        autoprefixer: {
            browsers: ['last 3 versions', '> 1%', 'ie >= 10'],
        },
        browserSync: {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 3000
        }
    }
}
```

Bonus question: is it possible to watch without having Webpack 4 start up a new devServer?
Thanks! <3

Comment: Can you add your webpack configuration?, it seems you are missing a path `Error: Can't resolve './src' in [MY PATH HERE]`

Comment: The path prints correctly, I just decided to ommit it for the sake of readability. Updated the question with a config though!